widetilde and widehat differences between xelatex and lualatex
A user of NewCM noted that xelatex and lualatex produce different results on the same simple tex code (and not only NewCM). The code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[regular]{newcomputermodern}
\begin{document}
\[
\widetilde{X}, \widetilde{B}, \widetilde{Y}, \widetilde{V}, \widetilde{A}
\]
\[
\widehat{X}, \widehat{B}, \widehat{Y}, \widehat{V}, \widehat{A}
\]
\end{document}

produce expected results with xelatex (for example the tildes)

but with Lualatex it is wrong:

Since I develop NewCM I wonder if there is something I can do about this or it is a problem of the engine that should be reported elsewhere. Other than NewCM fonts have also this issue with lualatex.

Just to clarify, do you expect to get a wider tilde over all character, for example $\widetilde{I}$ too?

Just to add: The \widetilde is using "303, which has horisontal variants. If we look at the bounding boxes of the letters, that might explain why it gets wider for some letters and not for others.

I expect a consistent behavior. The bounding boxes are not different for xelatex and lualatex. And I can not alter the bounding boxes of the letters as these are the same with Knuth fonts.

LuaTeX seems to be consistent here, using the horisontal variant mechanism, as it is supposed to. I have no clue what is the reasoning behind what XeTeX does, though.

One way to come out of this is: Add the ic to the width, and then remove ic. Also, add a negative bottom right corner kern of the same size as original ic. Then the font will likely work well in both engines.

It boils down to the rather well known fact/problem that xetex and luatex handles italic correction differently in math. luatex only inserts an italic correction if another char follows and as this is not the case here, the Y is noticably smaller and the smaller variant of the accent is choosen.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[regular]{newcomputermodern}

\begin{document}\showoutput
{\fontspec{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}\fbox{^^^^^^01d44c}\fbox{^^^^^^01d434}}

\[
\widetilde{Y} \widetilde{A}
\]

\[
\widetilde{Y\Uchar"200D} \widetilde{A} %with zero-width joiner
\]

\end{document}

with lualatex

with xelatex

The difference can also be seen in the log:
with lualatex
...\vbox(8.84+0.0)x7.9, direction TLT
.....\hbox(6.51+0.0)x0.0, shifted 1.45001, direction TLT 
......\TU/NewCMMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 ̃
.....\kern-4.5 (font)     
.....\hbox(6.83+0.0)x5.81, direction TLT %<-------- 5.81 width
......\TU/NewCMMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 
....\vbox(10.17+0.0)x7.5, direction TLT
.....\hbox(7.51+0.0)x0.0, shifted 2.23999, direction TLT
......\TU/NewCMMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 
.....\kern-4.5 (font)
.....\hbox(7.16+0.0)x7.5, direction TLT
......\TU/NewCMMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 

with xelatex
....\vbox(9.86+0.0)x7.9
.....\hbox(7.53+0.0)x0.0, shifted 0.1
......\TU/NewCMMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 glyph#4626
.....\kern-4.5
.....\hbox(6.83+0.0)x7.9   %<-------- 7.9 width = 5.81 + 2.09
......\TU/NewCMMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 glyph#2150
......\kern2.09 %<------------- positive kern
....\vbox(10.17+0.0)x7.5
.....\hbox(7.51+0.0)x0.0, shifted 2.24
......\TU/NewCMMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 glyph#4616
.....\kern-4.5
.....\hbox(7.16+0.0)x7.5
......\TU/NewCMMath-Regular.otf(1)/m/n/10 glyph#2126


I just want to make sure it is not a font bug. The above seems to say that it is NOT a font issue but rather a different way to handle things between xelatex and lualatex. If true I will consider this closed (from the font side). Thanks.

as suggested in the comments you probably could remove the italic correction for the math chars and add them to the width.

But wouldn't this break metric compatibility with CM?
